# Query to get total amount of value depending on many id's?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, the first table is is Apartments and it has ApartmentID and the other table is Rooms and has RoomsID, I'm trying to get the total amount of rooms per apartment but my issue is that, the total isn't a value of itself, the room table has a row for each room custom values, so if I run something like this `SELECT * FROM Rooms` I will get all data like this

> ApartmentID = 1 , RoomID = 1 , WallPaint = Red etc...
>
> ApartmentID = 1 , RoomID = 2 , WallPaint = blue etc...

As you can see, I can have several rooms that belongs to ApartmentID 1

What I want to achieve is, a query that returns for me the amount of Rooms for All Apartment ID, Like I'm trying to get such a response from server

> ApartmentID 1 has 4 Rooms
>
> ApartmentID 2 has 3 Rooms

This is just an example but ofcourse the response will be in JSON.
I though about doing INNER JOIN query to get the data, but that only got me data I need for ApartmentID 1, how to I loop through all ApartmentID and for each ApartmentID I get the total Rooms in it keeping in mind that I need to count all rows for rooms and return the total as a value

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1). You want to `GROUP BY`

Comment: where is your inner join attempt?

Comment: You probably want something like `SELECT ApartmentID, COUNT(*) AS Roomcount FROM rooms GROUP BY ApartmentID`. (And in general, you should be working through a SQL tutorial at this point, that explains stuff like this.)

Comment: @Dharman That is not even close to duplicate

Comment: i don't understand why is this getting dowvoted

Comment: it's not type of homework, i started php literally yesterday and it's just something i want to pickup, i posted all the info i have, although i agree that i mentioned INNER JOIN solution but didn't post, because i tried it and already removed it since it didn't work so i didn't want to write it again. my fault on that part.

Comment: @Justinas I was under inpression that the problem is with broken PHP code which doesn't work because OP tried to use extension which was removed years ago from PHP. I will retract my vote and remove the misleading PHP code from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` in query:

```
SELECT ApartmentID, COUNT(RoomId) as RoomsCount FROM Rooms GROUP BY ApartmentID
```

That will give you one apartment per row with total of rooms.

Comment: i will try that and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a table for Apartments, and Rooms, you could do something like so:

```
// Some example data: 
create table Apartments(id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into Apartments(id, name) values(1, "apt 1");
insert into Apartments(id, name) values(2, "apt 2");
insert into Apartments(id, name) values(3, "apt 3");


create table Rooms(id integer, name varchar(100), apt_id int);
insert into Rooms(id, name, apt_id) values(1, "room 1 in apt 1", 1);
insert into Rooms(id, name, apt_id) values(2, "room 2 in apt 1", 1);
insert into Rooms(id, name, apt_id) values(3, "room 3 in apt 2", 2);
insert into Rooms(id, name, apt_id) values(4, "room 4 in apt 1", 1);
insert into Rooms(id, name, apt_id) values(5, "room 5 in apt 2", 2);

// Query to fetch each apartment and count of rooms for each one.
SELECT a.name, 
  (SELECT count(apt_id) 
  FROM `Rooms` r 
  WHERE r.apt_id = a.id) count
FROM `Apartments` a;

// Results:
apt 1:  3
apt 2:  2
apt 3:  0
```

Comment: @John - I recreated the table structure only to create a query for you and test it -- just change my `apt_id` to your `ApartmentID` :)

Comment: i don't understand your 'r' and 'a' what are they ?

Comment: They are just aliases, so you don't have to keep typing "Apartments", you can use the "a".   It is the same as: `SELECT Apartments.name, 
  (SELECT count(apt_id) 
  FROM Rooms 
  WHERE Rooms.apt_id = Apartments.id) count
FROM Apartments;`

Comment: yea i figured that, but they are causing me issues :( giving me unkown coloumns listed for 'a'

Comment: Make sure you use your actual IDentifiers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214730/discussion-between-john-and-stuart).